# createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element in React Test file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, react-18

I'm using React-18.0.0 in my project and in the test file I'm getting an error something below

> createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

My test file is :

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

test("renders learn react link", () => {
    root.render(<App />);
    const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Hello React/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: This article helped me. I was using the ID in my App.js but its the root ID in the index.html file - https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-createroot-target-container-not-dom-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test` uses `root.render(<App />)` while React's [`testing-library`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) provides there own `render` function to use inside a `test`

Retrieving the `root` isn't needed, and is causing the error you're showing.

So, apply the following change:

```js
// Remove
root.render(<App />);

// Replace with
render(<App />);  // Imported from @testing-library/react
```

---

Example of working `App.test.js`:

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const linkElement = screen.getByText(/this should exist/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: I am also using `import {render} from "@testing-library/react";` with vitest but still getting the same error
Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
 ❯ createRoot node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29345:11